# SSL error during data download from overpass turbo site using python

Tags: python, ssl, openstreetmap, overpass-api

After several compilations of my code an SSL error showed up.

Error fetching data: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='overpass-api.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/interpreter (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1129)')))
Data download failed.

Yesterday my code was working properly and was downloading data, but now it seems i send too many requests.

This is my code and over pass turbo query which should download all data for tourism key, and works properly on overpass turbo site.

How can i fix it?

```
`import requests

overpass_url = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter" 
key = "tourism"

overpass_query = f"""
    [out:json][timeout:10000];
    {{geocodeArea:Poland}}->.searchArea;
    (
    node["{key}"](area.searchArea);
    way["{key}"](area.searchArea);
    relation["{key}"](area.searchArea);
    );
    out body;
    >;
    out skel qt;
"""

def download_data(overpass_url, overpass_query):
    try:
        response = requests.post(overpass_url, data=overpass_query)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Error fetching data:", e)
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = download_data(overpass_url, overpass_query)
    if data:
        # Process and use the data as needed
        print("Data downloaded successfully.")
    else:
        print("Data download failed.")
`
```

Comment: You should probably familiarize yourself with the difference between Overpass API and overpass turbo. You're using `{{geocodeArea:Poland}}->.searchArea;`, which is an overpass turbo extension only available in the web frontend. In any case, even if you sort out the SSL issue, your query would be invalid syntax for the Overpass API backend.